# interface xxx cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments:

Tags: java

```
implements GenericObserver<DataService, Tools>, GenericObserver<MobileService, Tools>
```

cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments.

This is my interface:

```
public interface GenericObserver<S, D> {

    void update(S sender, D data);
}
```

What can I do? I need `DataService` and `MobileService`.

I try to use generic `T` instead of `DataService` and `MobileService` but I get an error that `T` does not exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interface I cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: I<String> and I<String>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9376059/interface-i-cannot-be-implemented-more-than-once-with-different-arguments-istr)

Comment: it is not a string. it is class not string...

Comment: @AdamMatan: That particular question looks to be more about a particular quirk (ie bug) of Eclipse's Java 1.7 compiler than a general question about the problem of implementing two instantiations of a generic interface. There surely are existing questions about that, but that isn't one of them.

Comment: @TomAnderson Thanks, I was too hasty in this one.

Comment: Can also occour having same generics. FYI: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=499344

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility:

```
abstract class Service {}

class DataService extends Service {}

class MobileService extends Service {}

class Foo implements GenericObserver<Service, Tools> {
    void update(Service sender, Tools data) {
        if (sender instanceOf DataService) {
            // do something
        } else if (sender instanceOf MobileService) {
            // do something else
        } else {
            // throw some notImplemented exception
        }
    }
}
```

The [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is another possibility (`GenericObserver` being the visitable).

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer has been eventually chosen. What xlecoustillier said above is 100% correct and the "one possibility" presented in this answer completely defeats the purpose of having a "strongly typed" language aspect of Java. A rule of a thumb has always been and will continue to be: if you can validate the types statically, then prefer it to RT downcasting.  Otherwise we wouldn't have had TypeScript in modern age. Also prefer polymorphism to switch blocks. As a mind excercise this solution is fine, but it should not be used as a general purpose guidance.

Answer (score 16):

This is because of Java doing [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). After compilation, all generic types are erased, both interfaces ending looking the same in the bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

The implementing class can provide these interfaces as *capabilities* providing a **lookup** method as below. The advantage of this pattern, is extendibility and uncoupling of the API of the classes.

```
interface DataObserver extends GenericObserver<DataService, Tools> { }

interface MobileObserver extends GenericObserver<MobileService, Tools> { }

public class Implementor {

    private DataObserver dataObserver;
    private MobileObserver mobileObserver;

    public <T> T lookup(Class<T> klazz) {
        ... return dataObserver;
    }

}
```

Comment: Fact that we have to write separate interfaces, we can have separate implementations only for a cleaner solution!

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible scenarios why are you trying to do this:

This first one - both GenericObserver and GenericObserver are essential to implementing class interface. In this case you probably have a design flaw because objects should be made as specialized as possible (i.e. it is better to have two different classes each concentrating on a specialized task rather then one class mixing both of them). So you probably should create two separate classes, one implementing GenericObserver and another one implementing GenericObserver. When you try to implement GenericObserver twice with different type arguments the compiler complains because generics in Java are implemented using erasure and hence GenericObserver and GenericObserver are essentially the same GenericObserver at runtime.

The second scenario - these interfaces are part of your implementation details. Then you can use inner classes (or static nested classes) to achieve your goal. For example:

```
public class OuterClass {

    private String hello = "Hello";
    private String world = "World";

    private class InnerClass1 implements GenericObserver<DataService, Tools> {
        public String interfaceMethod() {
            return hello + " " + world;
        }
        // more implementation
    }

    private class InnerClass2 implements GenericObserver<MobileService, Tools> {
        // implementation
    }

}
```

If you use inner classes then you can easily access fields of encompassing class as you can see from this a bit contrived example.